# selecting specific value from a dataframe in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am working with the below dataframe in R:

```
library(quantmod)
etSymbols("AAPL",from="2022-10-15",to="2022-10-31")
AAPL

> AAPL
           AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
2022-10-17    141.07    142.90   140.27     142.41    85250900        142.41
2022-10-18    145.49    146.70   140.61     143.75    99136600        143.75
2022-10-19    141.69    144.95   141.50     143.86    61758300        143.86
2022-10-20    143.02    145.89   142.65     143.39    64522000        143.39
2022-10-21    142.87    147.85   142.65     147.27    86464700        147.27
2022-10-24    147.19    150.23   146.00     149.45    75981900        149.45
2022-10-25    150.09    152.49   149.36     152.34    74732300        152.34
2022-10-26    150.96    151.99   148.04     149.35    88194300        149.35
2022-10-27    148.07    149.05   144.13     144.80   109180200        144.80
2022-10-28    148.20    157.50   147.82     155.74   164762400        155.74
```

May I ask, if I want to select a specific row based on date, say if I wanna select the closing price of AAPL (AAPL$AAPL.Close) on 2022-10-27, how should I do? Thank you so much.

Comment: `AAPL['2022-10-27', ]` should return the whole row. `AAPL['2022-10-27', 'AAPL.Close']` should return just that column.

Comment: if you want to use dplyr check how to use `filter` function